# Error 1064 for no apparently reason

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I got this query:

```
SELECT  companies_comments.id as id, 
        companies_comments.post as post, 
        companies_comments.comment as comment, 
        companies_comments.date as date, 
        companies.`id` AS company, 
        companies.`name` as name, 
        companies.`username` as username, 
        companies.`photo` as photo, 
        companies.`status` AS company_status
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = companies_comments.company
WHERE company_status NOT IN (3,4)
AND companies_comments.post =1
```

The error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = companies_comments.company     WHERE compa' at line 10`

Error 1064 unexpectedly. Just tried with no ` , same results. No missing column. What can be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the tablename and also a `FROM` section in the query

```
SELECT  companies_comments.id as id, 
        companies_comments.post as post, 
        companies_comments.comment as comment, 
        companies_comments.date as date, 
        companies.`id` AS company, 
        companies.`name` as name, 
        companies.`username` as username, 
        companies.`photo` as photo, 
        companies.`status` AS company_status
FROM companies, companies_comments
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = companies_comments.company
WHERE companies.company_status NOT IN (3,4)
AND companies_comments.post =1
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added FROM what table.You have missed the from part.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
```